# Driver [session] not supported. in laravel 5.2 Error?

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, laravel-5

When I am using `Auth::check()` or `Auth::logout()` or `Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)`

I am getting following error,

```
InvalidArgumentException in Manager.php line 90: Driver [session] not supported.
```

[image]

I am helpless to solve the issue?

Comment: Please post code that causes the error.

Comment: In `Http/Kernel.php` is your `StartSession` middleware enabled?

Comment: @jszobody it is there inside `$middlewareGroups`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin when I am using `Auth`..throwing the error..

Comment: any hope ?? :( .....

Comment: The error is in your OfferController according to your screenshot, but like @AlexeyMezenin says, "Please post code that causes the error." before anyone can help you.

Comment: Run 'PHP artisan config:cache'

Comment: If that doesn't work post any changes you have made related to Auth. Maybe post them anyway

Comment: Thank you all for supporting... i fixed problem by changing `SESSION_DRIVER` from session to `file` at `.env` file. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change config/session.php driver to database or file and don't forget to restart your laravel app(close your terminal and open your terminal again and enter "php artisan serve") after you make the changes

Answer (score 0):

Change config/session.php driver to database or file